# Chrome dev channel, update stuck on 'Updating google chrome'

Tags: google-chrome

Steps taken:

1. Initially, updating was working fine.
2. Two days ago, clicked 'enable automatic updates for all users' in about:chrome
3. Then received 'chrome Update failed (error: 11)'
4. Searched on how to resolve that issue. The solution was to run 'defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0' and 'sudo rm -rf /Library/Google' (which I backed up)
5. Today, I went to check for chrome updates. It said update found, and now it's been stuck on 'updating chrome' for ~10 mins. Have tried restarting, and also re-deleting /Library/Chrome

Comment: We have no idea what OS you are running, that might help, or it could make no difference still good information to have.

Comment: You are completely right. Oops! Was Mac OS 10.11.2. Though it turns out the problem has magically resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have resolved itself without any action on my part.